# ASP.NET MVC OAuth2 Pass Provider Additional Data to be Returned on URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to locate documentation or examples on how to send additional data to Google+, Facebook, Twitter, etc so that it can be passed back to the `ExternalLoginCallback` method.

I am using OAuth as the means to 'register' a user and need to know what type of 'user' is attempting to register.  They can be a 'customer' or 'business' user.

In the `ExternalLoginCallback` there is a place where the app tries to log the user in (after returning from the provider authentication) and, if the signin fails, the user is sent to the `ExternalLoginConfirmation` view where we finalize their registration.  This is the point where I need to know if the user came from my site as a customer registration or a business registration.